# What is the best route to convert my easa licence and ratings to FAA equal?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, easa

I currently hold an EASA frozen ATPl, CPL, MEP, SEP, IR, CFI, APS MCC, UPRT,.... .

I converted my PPL A licence to FAA PPL with the SEP rating.

Now I wonder what the best route is to convert all the other ratings and licences in the easiest and most cost efficient way.